# Magento On First Load Some ESI Blocks Slow

Tags: magento-1.9, varnish, turpentine

Hi we are using Magento 1.9 with Turpentine Varnish. When varnish serves non cached pages some ESI blocks load very slow. Is there any way to diagnose and fix this issue? One of the suspected ESI blocks is 'global_messages' template which load core/messages block.